# Divergence of the sum of convergent and divergent series (proof check)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that if  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ diverges then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{n}+b_{n}\right)$ diverges.

By defining $k_{n}=s_{n}+t_{n}$, where $s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \text { and } t_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{n}$ (the nth partial sums),  can I prove this simply by noting that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}  k_{n}= \lim_{n \to \infty}  (s_{n} + t_{n}) = L \pm \infty = \pm \infty $$

$$?$$
The book I'm following uses a proof by contradiction but this approach seems more straightforward, although I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct. You seem to assume that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=\pm\infty$. Actually, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges if and only if the sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges. And, if the sequence $(s_n+t_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ was convergent with limit $L'$, then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl((s_n+t_n)-s_n\bigr)=L'-L.$$And this is a contradiction.